Доступ к Firebase в серверном приложении на Dart
Контекст:
Я собираюсь написать клиент-серверное приложение: клиент будет на flutter, а сервер - на Dart. Для работы с БД я решил использовать firebase т.к. проект учебный. Доступ к БД и аккаунтам только у сервера (как и основная работа приложения) - клиент только запрашивает нужные данные или изменения.
Суть проблемы заключается в том, что из библиотек firebase для dart для сервера по идее есть библиотека firebase_admin (если я правильно понял, она именно для таких целей), однако код, указанный в документации не работает у меня:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;
import 'package:firebase_admin/firebase_admin.dart';
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  var app = FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp(AppOptions(
    credential: ServiceAccountCredential('service-account.json'),
  ));

  // остальной код
}


возникает ошибка:
The function 'ServiceAccountCredential' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'ServiceAccountCredential', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'ServiceAccountCredential'.

И это не смотря на то, что именно так указано в документации здесь
Суть вопроса:
Я что-то делаю не так или проблема в самой библиотеке? Может пример в статье не актуальный?
P.s. Лично у меня после всех мучений сложилось ощущение, что конкретно firebse_admin либо в целях безопасности перестала поддерживаться, либо просто пока ещё не рабочая

Похоже в примере действительно только пример, судя по документации в firebase_admin нет ServiceAccountCredential.
Но есть другой способ:
AppOptions(
    credential: FirebaseAdmin.instance.certFromPath('service-account.json'),
  )

Либо вы можете создать свой класс на основе Credential со своей реализацией:
class ServiceAccountCredential extends Credential {
  @override
  Future<AccessToken> getAccessToken() {...}
}

